# Regex for validating alpha_dash and exactly one dot symbol

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate names of uploaded files. For now, I have the following regex which matches only alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores:

```
/^[\w-]*$/
```

However, I need to also ensure, that **the filename contains exactly one dot** character. How should I modify this regex to achieve the desired result?

Comment: _about your regex_, be careful, it may seem correct but **[`it is not exactly what you think`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1757/character-classes/9991/character-class-and-common-problems-faced-by-beginner#t=201608061800584842834)**

Comment: @rock321987 I've heard that before, but still don't understand the difference between `[\w]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The [Stack Overflow docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1757/character-classes#t=201608062355504305058&a=remarks-common-classes-1) say, that they are equal, btw.

Comment: you have edited your question now..the regex you were using was `^[\w-\.]*$` and `-` inside character class denotes range and it won't match `-` literally

Comment: and regarding `\w`, regex engine of some languages allow `\w` to match characters of non english characters..e.g. **[`.net`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b&i=%d7%a2%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%aa)**

Comment: @rock321987 I see, thanks. I fixed my previous regex, because I had initially copied it with mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull the period out of your character class, like this:

```
/^[\w-]*\.[\w-]*$/
```